# いる connected to a proposition?

Tags: verbs, syntax

I'm stuck with the construction of 居る/いる in the following sentence (Botchan, I)

> 小学校【しょうがっこう】に居【い】る時分【じぶん】学校【がっこう】の二階【にかい】から飛【と】び降【お】りて一週間【いっしゅうかん】ほど腰【こし】を抜【ぬ】かした事【こと】がある。

My translation (excuse my poor English) :

> **Being** at the elementary school, it happened that I jumped from the second story of the school, my back broken for about a week.

I understand this 居る as if it was a [determiner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner), linked to the word "時分". But I can't figure out how 居る時分 is linked to the sentence : does 居る somehow introduce 小学校に (*confer* my translation) ?

Comment: [Japanese doesn't have any determiners.](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/7260/2081)

Comment: Indeed ! So, what's the gramatical category of "居る" in the sentence above ?

Comment: It is just a regular 動詞.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a description of the period of time when this happened. "During the time I was in elementary school". 小学校に居る modifies 時分. During which period did this happen? During the period when I was in school.